# relationship between length of eigen vector and the magnitude of associated eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have some square matrix $A$ and if we can decompose it to find its eigenvector and their associated eigenvalue.
Will the length of eigenvector associated with largest eigenvalue always be greater than or equal to any other eigenvector?
Are there any special properties associated with length of eigenvector if matrix $A$ is symmetric? Or if $A$ is positive semi definite?

Comment: In general you end up with a whole subspace of eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue so this question doesn't really mean anything. You can pick an eigenvector with arbitrary length.

Comment: so the eigen vector associated with smallest eigen value can have larger magnitude than that of the larger eigen vector. There is no particular relationship between length of the eigen vector and its associated eigen value?

Comment: There is not just one eigenvector associated to an eigenvalue, so you can't say 'the' eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue. In general, eigenvalues need not be real so then you need to clarify what you mean by the 'smallest' eigenvalue. I would suggest you do some examples with actual matrices/linear operators and see what the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors are.

Comment: If $x$ in an eigenvector of $A$, $kx$ is as well for every scalar $k\ne 0$. Therefore the eigenvectors are normalized: $||x|| = 1$.

Comment: While the comments are valid I still think it's a genuine question.  Packages like MATLAB return "eigenvectors" (`[V,D] = eig(A)` in the documentation it says the columns of the matrix V are the "corresponding right eigenvectors, so that A*V = V*D").  So one might wonder, how long are these vectors and does their length matter?

Answer (score 2):

there is no such thing as the "length of an eigenvector". Eigenvectors are class of equivalences only encoding *directions*. The *scaling* along this axis is given by the eigenvalue.

( NB: axis and scaling mentioned here are in the case of a real eigenvalue ).